# Is creating html page for each user profile a good practice?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, unique, user-profile

I'm working on startup project and i have company profile for each employer contains images , videos , and some contents save to database, i'm thinking to create html page for each company and save it to the server and direct users to this page instead of one page and retrieve data each time.

and of course each time if some data changed for one company from our dashboard we will replace the exists one with the new content and save it to the server

**Is it a good practice or not ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a good practice if you want to create a different page for each company, but this method could become tricky to administrate when you have a lot of company under you. Generally i suggest you to use a standart html page for every company, and improve the user page customization.

**Edit:**

Create a path for each company profile, e.g. www.domain.com/company

Comment: I have one layout for company profile, my idea I don't want to retrieve data from database each time visiting profile !

Comment: Indeed i wrote to use a single html file for every company. Make a subdomain for each one: domain.com/company

Comment: great , this is what i'm thinking to do.  thank you so much

Comment: using a subdomain is overkill and can cause unintended cross origin issues

Comment: @charlietfl It's what most hosting sites does

Comment: if use any ajax will have to set up CORS ... simpler to keep it on main domain. No need for separate sub  domains for small scale site

Comment: @charlietfl keep it on the main domain do not cause any kind of problem/difficulties

Comment: that is not what a subdomain is. You are talking about a directory or path...not subdomain

Comment: @charlietfl You right, i mean a directory for each company page. i will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice would be to create a template html page, and fill that template with code from a database - there for storing all the information for each employer in the database, and populating the template with that data.

That being said, if you just have a few employers, it may be 'faster' to just create individual html files for each employers profile.  You should use this method only to get your website off the ground, and opt to use a template style once the business scales.